# Azure Media Player Uncaught Error: cannot find the request in the request queue

Tags: azure-media-services, apache-cordova

I have a problem I do not know how to solve, I do not know if it's a bug of 'azure media player' but when I view a streaming video shows me this error "'Uncaught Error: cannot find the request in the request queue azuremediaplayer.min.js (2,338210)' but if I see a local video as a mp4 does not give me any problems. What could be the problem? Excuse my English.

By the way, I'm using Ripple to emulate Android, if I visualize from a physical device does not give me problems.

Thanks

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);

    var myOptions = {
      "nativeControlsForTouch": false,
      controls: false,
      autoplay: false,
      width: "640px",
      height: "360px",
      poster: "",
      logo: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
    var myPlayer = amp("azuremediaplayer", myOptions);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
        document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
        document.addEventListener( 'resume', onResume.bind( this ), false );

        // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.
        //var element = document.getElementById("deviceready");
        //element.innerHTML = 'Device Ready';
        //element.className += ' ready';
        myPlayer.src([
        {
          //"src": "movie/Rutina.mp4",
          //"type": "video/mp4"
          "src": "http://amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/830584f8-f0c8-4e41-968b-6538b9380aa5/TearsOfSteelTeaser.ism/manifest",
          "type": "application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml",
          "protectionInfo": [
                  {
                    "type": "AES",
                    "authenticationToken": "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1cm46bWljcm9zb2Z0OmF6dXJlOm1lZGlhc2VydmljZXM6Y29udGVudGtleWlkZW50aWZpZXIiOiI5ZGRhMGJjYy01NmZiLTQxNDMtOWQzMi0zYWI5Y2M2ZWE4MGIiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vdGVzdGFjcy5jb20vIiwiYXVkIjoidXJuOnRlc3QiLCJleHAiOjE3MTA4MDczODl9.lJXm5hmkp5ArRIAHqVJGefW2bcTzd91iZphoKDwa6w8"
                  }
          ]
        }
        ]);

        myPlayer.autoplay(true);
    };

    function onPause() {
      // TODO: This application has been suspended. Save application state here.
    };

    function onResume() {
        // TODO: This application has been reactivated. Restore application state here.
    };
} )();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
      Customize the content security policy in the meta tag below as needed. Add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src to enable inline JavaScript.
      For details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=617521
  -->
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src http://amp.azure.net 'self' data: gap: blob: https://ssl.gstatic.com http://amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src  'self'; media-src http://localhost:4400/ blob:">


  <title>Mobile</title>
  <link href="lib/ionic/release/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.6.3/skins/amp-default/azuremediaplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.6.3/azuremediaplayer.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <video id="azuremediaplayer" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered"></video>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/ionic/release/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, using an emulator for video playback can be an unreliable testing scenario. The issue you're seeing could very well be unique to the emulator itself, which can be dependent on the performance of the machine your emulator is running on as well as the capabilities of the emulator.

You are better of testing your code on a physical device, especially if the issue is not occurring on it.